# magento cms content page showing empty

Tags: magento-1.9

In magento backend i can't able to add content, it showing empty. check my image it won't have editor

[image]

Comment: Do you have any errors in you browser's  console?

Comment: i already checked No error

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to go to:

> /js/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/plugins/magentowidget and copy this file to the desktop: editor_plugin.js.

Then go to:

> /js/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/plugins/ and create a directory called: magentotypo.

Finally, paste editor_plugin.js into the directory magentotypo.

Done!

Comment: No it's not working i had already that folder also that js